# Running subprocesses command with two string inputs

Tags: python, bash, variables, subprocess

I'm trying to validate a certificate with a CA bundle file. The original Bash command takes two file arguments like this;

```
openssl verify -CAfile ca-ssl.ca cert-ssl.crt
```

I'm trying to figure out how to run the above command in python subprocess whilst having ca-ssl.ca and cert-ssl.crt as variable strings (as opposed to files).

If I ran the command with variables (instead of files) in bash then this would work;

```
ca_value=$(<ca-ssl.ca)
cert_value=$(<cert-ssl.crt)

openssl verify -CAfile <(echo "$ca_value") <(echo "$cert_value")
```

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to do the above with Python, preferably without needing to use `shell=True`. I have tried the following but doesn't work and instead prints 'help' commands for openssl;

```
certificate = ''' cert string '''
ca_bundle = ''' ca bundle string '''

def ca_valid(cert, ca):
    ca_validation = subprocess.Popen(['openssl', 'verify', '-CAfile', ca, cert], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  bufsize=1)
    ca_validation_output = ca_validation.communicate()[0].strip()
    ca_validation.wait()

ca_valid(certificate, ca_bundle)
```

Any guidance/clues on what I need to look further into would be appreciated.

Comment: As an easy way out, would you consider using [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module?

Comment: Maybe use `os.system()` instead?

Comment: are you sure you have the command right? when I run the command that would be constructed by your list directly in a terminal, I also get openssl's usage help string.

Comment: One more thing, you forgot to `import subprocess`

Comment: Process substitution actually does use files in `/dev/fd/` You may want to just use [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) to create a NamedTemporaryFile object, write to it, and pass its .name attribute to subprocess.

Comment: @xgord It works, make sure you're using a valid CA bundle and certificate. Mine outputs; `openssl verify -CAfile ca-ssl.ca cert-ssl.crt
cert-ssl.crt: C = US, O = "thawte, Inc.", OU = Certification Services Division, OU = "(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = thawte Primary Root CA`. I'm going to try the tempfile solution, thanks for the responses guys.

Answer (score 1):

Bash process substitution `<(...)` in the end is supplying a file path as an argument to  `openssl`.

You will need to make a helper function to create this functionality since Python doesn't have any operators that allow you to inline pipe data into a file and present its path:

```
import subprocess
def validate_ca(cert, ca):
    with filearg(ca) as ca_path, filearg(cert) as cert_path:
        ca_validation = subprocess.Popen(
            ['openssl', 'verify', '-CAfile', ca_path, cert_path],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        return ca_validation.communicate()[0].strip()
```

Where `filearg` is a context manager which creates a named temporary file with your desired text, closes it, hands the path to you, and then removes it after the `with` scope ends.

```
import os
import tempfile
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanger
def filearg(txt):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as fh:
        fh.write(txt)
    try:
        yield fh.name
    finally:
        os.remove(fh.name)
```

Anything accessing this temporary file(like the subprocess) needs to work inside the context manager.

By the way, the  `Popen.wait(self)` is redundant since `Popen.communicate(self)` waits for termination.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use process substitution, you will *have* to use `shell=True`. This is unavoidable. The `<(...)` process substitution syntax is bash syntax; you simply must call bash into service to parse and execute such code.

Additionally, you have to ensure that `bash` is invoked, as opposed to `sh`. On some systems `sh` may refer to an old Bourne shell (as opposed to the Bourne-again shell `bash`) in which case process substitution will definitely not work. On some systems `sh` will invoke `bash`, but process substitution will still not work, because when invoked under the name `sh` the `bash` shell enters something called POSIX mode. Here are some excerpts from the `bash` man page:

> ...
>
> INVOCATION
>
> ... When invoked as sh, bash enters posix mode after the startup files are read. ....
>
> ...
>
> SEE ALSO
>
> ...
>
> http://tiswww.case.edu/~chet/bash/POSIX -- a description of posix mode
>
> ...

From the above web link:

> 28. Process substitution is not available.

`/bin/sh`  seems to be the default shell in python, whether you're using `os.system()` or `subprocess.Popen()`. So you'll have to specify the argument `executable='bash'`, or `executable='/bin/bash'` if you want to specify the full path.

This is working for me:

```
subprocess.Popen('printf \'argument: "%s"\\n\' verify -CAfile <(echo ca_value) <(echo cert_value);',executable='bash',shell=True).wait();
## argument: "verify"
## argument: "-CAfile"
## argument: "/dev/fd/63"
## argument: "/dev/fd/62"
## 0
```

---

Here's how you can actually embed the string values from variables:

```
bashEsc = lambda s: "'"+s.replace("'","'\\''")+"'";
ca_value = 'x';
cert_value = 'y';
cmd = 'printf \'argument: "%%s"\\n\' verify -CAfile <(echo %s) <(echo %s);'%(bashEsc(ca_value),bashEsc(cert_value));
subprocess.Popen(cmd,executable='bash',shell=True).wait();
## argument: "verify"
## argument: "-CAfile"
## argument: "/dev/fd/63"
## argument: "/dev/fd/62"
## 0
```